# SQL query to filter records based on count and status

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have to filter records based on the status when the count is more than 1.
Column names: Student_id, Status, term, and course.

DB: Postgres

Condition to filter:

1. If there exists only one record for the student then the status(true or false) does not matter. Fetch the record.
2. If record count for a student is more than one then fetch only those students whose status is true.
   (More than one record would mean, same Student_id, term, and course). At any given time there will be only one record with status as true.

How do I write the SQL query for this?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below query:

```
Create Table #TableA(
id int,
Student_id Varchar(100),
[Status] bit,
term int,
course varchar(10)
)

Insert Into #TableA Values(1, 1, 1, 3, 'C#')
Insert Into #TableA Values(2, 2, 0, 6, 'Php')
Insert Into #TableA Values(3, 2, 0, 6, 'Php')
Insert Into #TableA Values(4, 2, 1, 6, 'Php')
Insert Into #TableA Values(5, 2, 1, 7, 'Php')

Select a.id, a.Student_id, a.Status, a.term, a.course from 
(
Select *, count(*) over (Partition By Student_id, term, course) As row_count From #TableA
) a
Where a.row_count = 1 Or a.[Status] = 1
```

Result will be like below:

id  Student_id  Status  term    course

1   1   1   3   C#

4   2   1   6   Php

5   2   1   7   Php

Comment: Note that the syntax you use is invalid standard SQL and won't work on Postgres

Comment: I gave query in SQL query, the requester can change the syntax as per Postgre.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm  . . . You seem to want:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by student_id) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt = 1 or status;
```

This filters out students with more than one record and not `true` status.

If you really want one row per student, even students with no true status, then use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (student_id) t.*
from t
order by student_id, status desc;
```

Comment: In your solution, if there is a record with Student_id, term same but the course is different then I think, it will not give result as per his expectation.

Comment: @RajeevKumar . . . I think this does what you describe.  Without sample data and desired results, it is a little hard to tell, eh?  A SQL/DB fiddle would also help.

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion saved my day :) I had to do a little change in your solution and It worked as I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

CASE WHEN status='x' AND count>1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END